# GNU Assembler and Exception Vector Table

Tags: raspberry-pi, arm

I have been done the Baking Pi tutorial, and I have studied about SVC system call, in the Baking Pi tutorial, it set the base of my program is 0x8000 but the vector table base is 0, how do I access 0x0 by GNU assembler and use which kernel.ld I use now?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Pi you can start at 0x8000 or 0x80000 by default. There are now different filenames to guide the bootloader as to what mode you want the processor kernel.img, kernel7.img kernel32.img or some various combinations you can easily look this up.

The baking Pi first off had issues as written but asked and answered many times in the Raspberry Pi website baremetal forums (a very good resource, best I have seen in a long time if not ever).  You will need to be using an old old pi or a Pi Zero to get the tutorial to work unless it has been updated.

This is bare metal you own the whole address space if you want to put something at zero you simply do that.

Another approach is you can create a config.txt file and in that you can tell the bootloader in the GPU to load your image to 0x00000000 in the arms address space.  Depending on the arm core you are using you can also use a VTOR register if present to change where the vector table is (so set it at 0x80000 instead of 0x0000.  I don't think the arm11 in the Pi Zero or old old pis allows for that though.  32 bit mode on the newer ones does, but they are multi-core and that will unravel any learning exercises.  you have to "sort the cores" as I like to say on boot, isolating one to continue and putting the others in an infinite loop so they don't interfere. The boot code that the gpu lays down for you on those Pi's does this for you so that only one hits 0x8000 or 0x80000, so the config.txt approach is something folks contemplate, but I would recommend against it for a while.

There are a number of tutorials linked in the raspberrypi baremetal forum on their website that should take you well beyond the baking Pi one(s).  and/or help you through those as folks struggled with them for some time.

A linker script like this

```
MEMORY
{
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x8000, LENGTH = 0x10000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > ram
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > ram
    .bss : { *(.bss*) } > ram
    .data : { *(.data*) } > ram
}
```

with a bootstrap like this

```
.globl _start
_start:
    mov sp,#0x8000
    bl main
hang: b hang
```

should get you booted.

For the linker script you may need 0x80000 instead of 0x8000, and if you have at least one .data item, like a global variable:

```
unsigned int x = 5;
```

Then the bootstrap doesn't have to zero .bss (if your programming style is such that you rely on that).  objcopy will pad the -O binary file with zeros between .rodata and .data if there is .data there taking care of zeroing bss.

You can let the tools do the work for you as far as an exception table goes:

```
.globl _start
_start:
    ldr pc,reset_handler
    ldr pc,undefined_handler
    ldr pc,swi_handler
    ldr pc,prefetch_handler
    ldr pc,data_handler
    ldr pc,unused_handler
    ldr pc,irq_handler
    ldr pc,fiq_handler
reset_handler:      .word reset
undefined_handler:  .word hang
swi_handler:        .word hang
prefetch_handler:   .word hang
data_handler:       .word hang
unused_handler:     .word hang
irq_handler:        .word irq
fiq_handler:        .word hang

reset:
    mov r0,#0x8000
    mov r1,#0x0000
    ldmia r0!,{r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9}
    stmia r1!,{r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9}
    ldmia r0!,{r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9}
    stmia r1!,{r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9}
```

Now if this is not a Pi Zero then the vector table works differently you need to read the arm docs anyway before going off into stuff like this but read up on the core and mode as well as the architecture docs for whichever you are using.  The newer Pis have an armv7 mode and an armv8 mode (aarch32 and aarch64) and each has its own challenges, but they have all been covered in the forum.

Comment: But if I set vector table to _start or use .org the bootloader will run start by the first byte of kernel.img(it will run "ldr pc, =reset_handler" in your program), how do I avoid it?

Comment: _start is irrelevant here this is not an application being loaded by an operating system.  I just use it to get the tool to not give a warning.  .org is ancient use linker scripts or the command line options for linking.  you want the bootloader to run the first instruction in the binary that is the only way your program will work.  the first word must be an instruction

Comment: where can I sset boot address of kernel.img in config.txt?

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/  that took around 2 seconds to find using a search engine.

Comment: if you are asking these questions I strongly recommend against using config.txt

Comment: So in the bootloader default setting it will run start by the start of kernel.img, but I will use those space for vector table, have any simple way to make bootloader start at 0x8000 in the kernel.img?

Comment: in your sample, there are two _start then they cannot be link